# Add Double each time user clicks button on EditText

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I am making a budget app and each time the user enters a new expense, I just append a TextView. I need to add each expense together, but I'm not sure how to do this on each click.

First, I thought to simply add all the numbers from the TextView, but I couldn't find a way to do this since they're all in just one TextView (as opposed to creating a new TextView on each click). So, I decided to simply parse the expense each time the user types it then add them together. But how can I add them after parsing in this way?

Thanks so much for the help

```
 addExpenseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO: Transfer this info to line in scroll view showing expenses
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(enterExpensesEditText.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(enterExpensesNamesEditText.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(Expenses.this, "Expense Amount or Name Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String income = enterExpensesEditText.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    String incomeName = enterExpensesNamesEditText.getText().toString() + "\n";
                    expenseAmountTextView.append(income);
                    expenseNameTextView.append(incomeName);
                    //parse income to double in order to add it and later feed to EverydayBudget
                    totalIncome = Double.parseDouble(income);
                }
                enterExpensesNamesEditText.setText("");
                enterExpensesEditText.setText("");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parse only the current expense : `totalIncome = Double.parseDouble(income);`

maybe replace by `totalIncome += Double.parseDouble(income);`

Sorry guys but i don't understand your question where is the problem ? you append your textview when you have a new expense no ?

And why not use a ListView rather TextView ?

Comment: I realize I only parse the current expense - I am trying how to parse and add each expense. I tried replacing it with += but get a null pointer exception with that

Comment: I declared the double as 0.00 in my OnCreate then retried this code and it worked! Thanks!